# jQuery's $(this), closest() elements with ajax commands

Tags: ajax

I have a table with this structure.

```
<tr class="odd views-row-first">...</tr>
<tr class="even">
    <td class="views-field views-field-title">Some icon</td>
    <td class="views-field views-field-field-stavka-do-mesta">
        <a class="use-ajax ajax-processed" href="/services/nojs/load.serviceForm">Some Title</a>
    </td>
    <td class="views-field views-field-field-stavka-za-vyzov">Some Text</td>
    <td class="views-field views-field-field-service-note">Some Text</td>
    <td class="formHolderTd tdHidden">
        <div class="formHolderDiv">&nbsp;</div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="odd">...</tr>
<tr class="even">...</tr>
```

Whenever the users click the title field, I want to show only the closest `<tr>`'s formHolderTd and insert my custom form to it.
I want to do this with Drupal's AJAX, but commands like `ajax_command_insert()` or `ajax_command_html()` affect all formHolderTd, not the child of the closest `<tr>`
.
Is there any way to add an additional jQuery's `closest()` or `find()` methods to ajax commands, or do I have to create a custom ajax command for this?

Here is my testing callback:

```
function load_service_form($js = NULL) {
  $output = render(drupal_get_form('servicesForm'));
  if($js) {
    ctools_include('ajax');
    $commands = array();
    $commands[] = ajax_command_html('.formHolderDiv', $output);
    print ajax_render($commands);
    exit;
  }
  else {
    return $output;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello. Could you show us actual implementation of Drupal AJAX commands you found problematic?

Comment: @Mołot I edited my answer, added my testing code.

Comment: Is there a custom JS code that's sending the ajax request? This problem is exactly why you should use ID's instead of classes. I'm assuming you're using Views to create the table, but is there some sort of delta of a field that you can use to number the ID's, for example: formHolderDiv-0, formHolderDiv-1, formHolderDiv-2 etc. Then you need to modify the code that's sending the ajax request to pass the ID to the callback. In FAPI you simply specify it in the `'wrapper'`, but this is probably going to be different.

Comment: @Beebee Yes, you are right, I am also thinking about this: add row_id to the rows and pass that row_id as an argument to the ajax callback..